# What does it mean for God to glorify Jesus in Himself?

Tags: john, jesus

John 13:32 (NASB):

> if God is glorified in Him, God will also glorify Him in Himself, and will glorify Him immediately.

What does it mean for God to glorify Jesus in Himself? Is this glorification separate from the immediate glorification mentioned in the following sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Greek the concept of glory has to do with light or attention by visibility.  In Acts 22:11 ἀπὸ τῆς δόξης τοῦ φωτὸς ἐκείνου (NA28) means Paul was blinded "from the brightness of that light."  Brightness translates the Greek word for glory.

The Hebrew word for glory
כָּבֵד
means *heavy*, the idea of being taken seriously or honored.

Thus, the idea is both Jesus and the Father will be become visible (revealed) and taken seriously (honored) in that visibility.

This had been taking place through the other miracles Jesus performed.  Now, it would be through the resurrection.

> 11 This, the first of his signs, Jesus did at Cana in Galilee, and manifested his glory. And his disciples believed in him.
> (John 2:11, ESV)

> 4 But when Jesus heard it he said, “This illness does not lead to death. It is for the glory of God, so that the Son of God may be glorified through it.”
> (John 11:4, ESV)

> Jesus said to her, “Did I not tell you that if you believed you would see the glory of God?”
> (John 11:40, ESV)

> 3 Jesus answered, “It was not that this man sinned, or his parents, but that the works of God might be displayed in him. 4 We must work the works of him who sent me while it is day; night is coming, when no one can work. 5 As long as I am in the world, I am the light of the world.”
> (John 9:3–5, ESV)

Notice the context of this passage relates to Jesus' sacrificial death and resurrection.

> Now is the Son of Man glorified, and God is glorified in him. 32 If God is glorified in him, God will also glorify him in himself, and glorify him at once. 33 Little children, yet a little while I am with you. You will seek me, and just as I said to the Jews, so now I also say to you, ‘Where I am going you cannot come.’
> (John 13:31–33, ESV)

> By this my Father is **glorified**, that you bear much fruit and so prove to be my disciples. 9 As the Father has loved me, so have I loved you. Abide in my love. 10 If you keep my commandments, you will abide in my love, just as I have kept my Father’s commandments and abide in his love. 11 These things I have spoken to you, that my joy may be in you, and that your joy may be full.
> 12 “This is my commandment, that you love one another as I have loved you. 13 Greater love has no one than this, that someone **lay down his life** for his friends. 14 You are my friends if you do what I command you.
> (John 15:8–14, ESV)

This passage shows the unity of the glory between believers, Christ, and the Father.

> 12 “Truly, truly, I say to you, whoever believes in me will also do the works that I do; and greater works than these will he do, because I am going to the Father. 13 Whatever you ask in my name, this I will do, that the Father may be glorified in the Son. 14 If you ask me anything in my name, I will do it.
> (John 14:12–14, ESV)

Another passage relating glory to the death and resurrection:

> 17 When Jesus had spoken these words, he lifted up his eyes to heaven, and said, “Father, the hour has come; glorify your Son that the Son may glorify you, 2 since you have given him authority over all flesh, to give eternal life to all whom you have given him. 3 And this is eternal life, that they know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom you have sent. 4 I glorified you on earth, having accomplished the work that you gave me to do. 5 And now, Father, glorify me in your own presence with the glory that I had with you before the world existed.
> (John 17:1–5, ESV)

This passage discusses our unity related to the glory.

> 20 “I do not ask for these only, but also for those who will believe in me through their word, 21 that they may all be one, just as you, Father, are in me, and I in you, that they also may be in us, so that the world may believe that you have sent me. 22 The **glory** that you have given me I have given to them, that they may be one even as we are one, 23 I in them and you in me, that they may become perfectly one, so that the world may know that you sent me and loved them even as you loved me. 24 Father, I desire that they also, whom you have given me, may be with me where I am, to see my **glory** that you have given me because you loved me before the foundation of the world. 25 O righteous Father, even though the world does not know you, I know you, and these know that you have sent me. 26 I made known to them your name, and I will continue to make it known, that the love with which you have loved me may be in them, and I in them.”
> (John 17:20–26, ESV)

**Appendix**

Glory in the Old Testament was heavy and burdensome, associated with giving the Law which exposed sin.  Glory in the New Testament was associated with light, grace, and true, the revelation of salvation.

> 14 And the Word became flesh and dwelt among us, and we have seen his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father, full of grace and truth. 15 (...) 16 For from his fullness we have all received, grace upon grace. 17 For the law was given through Moses; grace and truth came through Jesus Christ. 18 No one has ever seen God; the only God, who is at the Father’s side, he has made him known.
> (John 1:14–18, ESV)

> 4 In him was life, and the life was the light of men. 5 The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.
> (John 1:4–5, ESV)

> 16 On the morning of the third day there were thunders and lightnings and a thick cloud on the mountain and a very loud trumpet blast, so that all the people in the camp trembled. 17 Then Moses brought the people out of the camp to meet God, and they took their stand at the foot of the mountain. 18 Now Mount Sinai was wrapped in smoke because the LORD had descended on it in fire. The smoke of it went up like the smoke of a kiln, and the whole mountain trembled greatly. 19 And as the sound of the trumpet grew louder and louder, Moses spoke, and God answered him in thunder. 20 The LORD came down on Mount Sinai, to the top of the mountain. And the LORD called Moses to the top of the mountain, and Moses went up.
> (Exodus 19:16-20, ESV)

> 15 Then Moses went up on the mountain, and the cloud covered the mountain. 16 The glory of the LORD dwelt on Mount Sinai, and the cloud covered it six days. And on the seventh day he called to Moses out of the midst of the cloud. 17 Now the appearance of the glory of the LORD was like a devouring fire on the top of the mountain in the sight of the people of Israel. 18 Moses entered the cloud and went up on the mountain. And Moses was on the mountain forty days and forty nights.
> (Exodus 24:15–18, ESV)

Comment: Great answer. I might also add "the father is in me and I in the father" and similar passages earlier in the last supper as related to this one.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! The Old/New Testament comparison was particularly helpful, as was were abundant references to Scripture!

Answer (score 1):

I put the verse before it so it gives it more context of the verse you're speaking about.

> 31Therefore when he had gone out, Jesus said, “Now is the Son of Man glorified, and God is glorified in Him;
>
> 32if God is glorified in Him, God will also glorify Him in Himself, and will glorify Him immediately.

What does it mean for God to glorify Jesus in Himself?

God's work has been accomplished through Jesus as the Son of Man in this verse.

Upon completion, God's Glory is given to the Son of Man with Himself.

God's word is alive and when thinking about it this afternoon it came to me that this was such a great revelation in the verse at hand.

He was going to glorify man through glorifying the Son of Man that represents the second Adam.

Jesus said, <“Now the Son of Man is glorified and God is glorified in him. John 13:32>

Man has always been wanting the glory of God and fallen short of it.  Failed to fulfill a goal. Missed the mark.

> For all did sin, and are come short of the glory of God —
> Romans 3:23

When God said let us make man in our image it definitely was a work of God the Father and His Son. Genesis 1:26

God and His Son are now going to accomplish, finish making man in the true image of God.

He glorifies the Son of Man and just as the righteousness of God is given to man through the faith and work of Jesus in the form of the son of man, so also God gives man glory through glorifying the Son of Man

2 Thessalonians 2:14

> To this he called you through our gospel, so that you may obtain the glory of our Lord Jesus Christ.

God gives to Christ first and this is a new glory being revealed because it's now given to the Son of Man.  This glory is from the Father Himself.

For from his fullness we have all received, grace upon grace.

Comment: please use the accepted formatting to add clarity and readability. It's not difficult - just add  > before any scripture quotes and add an extra line spacing before and after the quote.

Comment: +1 @Sherrie, good answer. Try to follow the formatting on this site. More people will upvote if you do :) Try grammarly.com :)

Comment: Thank you both so much for your help.  I have tried it on my phone and when I paste it something changes the format from my original.  Maybe I need to write everything on my computer first.  I am trying to learn how to work this format.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

NASB John 13:

> 31Therefore when he had left, Jesus *said, “Now is the Son of Man **glorified**, and God is **glorified** in Him; 32 if God is **glorified** in Him, God will also **glorify** Him in Himself, and will **glorify** Him immediately.

The word *glorify* is repeated 5 times here. The repetitions show the importance of this act. More specifically, it refers to the impending suffering and the ultimate crucifixion.

The Spirit is linked to "glorified" in John 7:39

> Now this he said about the **Spirit**, whom those who believed in him were to receive, for as yet the Spirit had not been given, because Jesus was not yet **glorified**.

The coming Helper (Spirit) is conditioned on Jesus' leaving (death) in John 16:7

> But I tell you the truth: it is to your advantage that I am **leaving**; for if I do not leave, the **Helper** will not come to you; but if I go, I will send Him to you.

In John 13, Jesus linked glorification to his crucifixion.